# ARIMA ACF and PACF

Tags: parameters, arima

can you check what p and q is suitable for this data? The data have been differentiated once due to its trend.

ACF of time series:

[image: ACF of time series]

PACF of time series:

[image: PACF of time series]

My codes are as follow:

```
plot_pacf(trainlogd.diff().dropna(), lags=40)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding both q(ACF graph) and p(PACF) graph is 0.